# Xcode cannot deploy to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, visual-studio-cordova

I got the error message "Xode cannot run using the selected device" when I try to deploy my project to my iphone (iOS 9.1).

Here are some screenshots :

[image]

[image]

[image]

And if I click on the "Reset" button of Signing identities, it would grey out, but it still show "Reset" next time I go in.

Does anyone has a suggestion dealing with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Xcode 100% up to date? What happens if you change the deployment target to 9.1?

Comment: You need XCode 7.1 to run apps on iOS 9.1. What xcode do you use?

Comment: Update Xcode solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deployment target is 9.0 while your iPhone device is 9.1. You should update Xcode to get the newest iOS available.